# How to make shallow routing work on nested next js routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I'm trying to recreate the instagram shallow routing logic, which looks like this:

1. user is on the `instagram.com/p/cristiano`.
2. clicks on one of the pictures.
3. url changes to `instagram.com/p/Cd0...`, instead of being taken to detail page, user is presented with modal
4. on modal exit url changes back to `instagram.com/p/cristiano`.

[image]

Here is how I'm trying to recreate this logic:

`shallowRoutingOrigin` is the page from where I am opening the modal:
could be either `savedworkouts`,`discovery` or `u/${username}`

```
  const handleShallowRoutingClick = (documentId: string) => {
    router.push(
      `/${shallowRoutingOrigin}?documentId=${documentId}`,
      `workoutpreview/${documentId}`,
      {
        shallow: true,
      }
    );
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  };

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    router.push(`/${shallowRoutingOrigin}`, undefined, {
      shallow: true,
    });
    setModalIsOpen(false);
  };
```

The following logic and desired effect **works** on `savedworkouts` and `discovery` pages, however when I try to open the modal from `u/${username}`, instead of masking. url as  `/workoutpreview/id1` it masks as `/u/workoutpreview/id1` and I get 404 this page not found error.

What makes this logic not work on the user page?

Comment: It masks the URL as `/u/workoutpreview/id1` because you're using `workoutpreview/${documentId}` in the `as` value (no initial `/` makes the path relative). You should add `/` at the beginning if you want it masked as `/workoutpreview/id1`.